# MonoTouch binding notifications in 3rd party library

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I am working to create bindings for IDTech CC swipers. I have been banging my head against this for a while. I am stuck on how to subscribe to events that are raised by the 3rd party library. Specifically, I need to know when a card swipe has occured.

```
//Notification identifiers used with NSNotificationCenter
//physical attachment related
extern NSString * const uniMagAttachmentNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagDetachmentNotification;
//connection related
extern NSString * const uniMagInsufficientPowerNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagPoweringNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagTimeoutNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagDidConnectNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagDidDisconnectNotification;
//swipe related
extern NSString * const uniMagSwipeNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagTimeoutSwipeNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagDataProcessingNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagInvalidSwipeNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagDidReceiveDataNotification;
//command related
extern NSString * const uniMagCmdSendingNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagCommandTimeoutNotification;
extern NSString * const uniMagDidReceiveCmdNotification;
//misc
extern NSString * const uniMagSystemMessageNotification;
```

The documentation says this should work:

```
    [Notification]
    [Field ("uniMagAttachmentNotification")]
    NSString uniMagAttachmentNotification { get; }
```

It doesn't compile.

```
obj/Debug/ios/magTechBinding/uniMag.g.cs(637,95): error CS0117: `MonoTouch.Constants' does not contain a definition for `magTechBindingLibrary'
obj/Debug/ios/magTechBinding/uniMag.g.cs(637,77): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn.dlopen(string, int)' has some invalid arguments
obj/Debug/ios/magTechBinding/uniMag.g.cs(637,77): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `string'
```

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you get it? Will you open source?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
[Field ("uniMagAttachmentNotification", "__Internal")]
```

The second parameter tells inside which library to look for the field. Without one the generator *presume* you'll have a constant ready for it.

Now since you'll be linking the 3rd party **static** (.a) library it will become part of the final executable. That's why `__Internal` must be used as the library name (it means looks inside the main executable).